# MongoDB: Handling integers too large for Int64

Tags: mongodb

I'm having a problem handling integers with Mongodb that are too large for the standard Int64 format. To give an example of the sorts of numbers we're talking about here: I mean something like 10683171315666225459389678813960790592

Now, I've considered turning this into a Decimal128 and that seems to work. The problem I run into is that I think MongoDB is truncating these values when I convert them. I'm using:

```
db.NuAIS.find().forEach( function (x) { x.HilbertVal = parseFloat(x.HilbertVal); db.NuAIS.save(x); });
```

So I read the db, convert each of those string values to Decimal and get: 1.0683171315666225e+37. My assumption was that MongoDB was storing the actual value despite what it declared.

Here's the thing though: these values seem truncated since, when I try to search using the original string on MongoCompass, I get multiple values returned for a supposedly unique string. I assume that mongoDB has truncated the decimals after X strings and so is just returning ones that match the first X digits of the search string, which means you get multiple matches instead of one.

Is my assumption here right? Is there a way to avoid this with decimals or just to skip the whole problem altogether by having ints larger than 64 bits? I'd leave it as a string but I need to work with them as digits, find things that fall within a range and such.

Thank you

Comment: `parseFloat` is going to return a floating point value,which is where your precision loss will occur.  You should be using the Decimal conversion function.  See here for ref: https://api.mongodb.com/python/3.4.0/api/bson/decimal128.html

Comment: Note that for the "mongo shell", which is actually what you appear to be using here the "function wrapper" would be `NumberDecimal(x.HibertVal)`. But that **must** be a "string" representative of the original long number form. However such a number here is **still too long** for even 128bits. So if you **must** store it, then you need to store as a "string" and then rely on external processing for math at the wider precision. But 128 is the limit for MongoDB I'm afraid.

Comment: You could also store as "binary" instead of "string", but the point here is that "math expressions" in query conditions is just not going to be allowed internally within the engine.

Comment: Thanks gahooa. Tried that, and yet it seems to cause all queries to fail, even when I use the seemingly truncated val given by the converted value.

Comment: Thanks Neil. That's uh...unfortunate to hear.